# Understanding the TfRecordDataset map function in more detail

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am reading my `TfRecordData` like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)

def _parse_function(example_proto):

    features = {
        'data':         tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'label':        tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'resolution':   tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)

    resolution = tf.cast(parsed_features['resolution'], tf.int32)
    tensor_feature1 = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features['data'])
    tensor_feature2 = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features['label'])
    ...

    input = tf.reshape(tensor_feature1, [1, 256, 256])
    output = tf.reshape(tensor_feature2, [1, 256, 256])

    return input, output
```

Here I can only parse a single feature at once. Is it possible to concatenate my features in order to stack the input samples somehow like this:

```
for i in range(0,20)
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    tensor_feature1 = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features['data'])

    inputs = tf.stack(tensor_feature1, axis=0) # shape = [20, 256, 256]
return inputs, output
```

** EDIT **

I made progress:

```
datasets = []

for idx in range(20):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, 'GZIP')
    dataset = dataset.skip(idx)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=tf.constant(FLAGS.num_parallel_calls, dtype=tf.int32))
    dataset = dataset.batch(20)
    datasets.append(dataset)
```

Since batch only gives me consecutive batches I used `.skip(idx)` in hope to offset my starting point in order to sth like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] --> [1,2][2,3][3,4] rather than: [1,2][3,4]
```

I am not sure whether this is correct tho. The only problem now is: I also load 20 outputs rather than just one output. I was thinking of using `zip` but for now I could not get it done.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to perform the per-element computation in [`Dataset.map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) and then use [`Dataset.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) to stack together consecutive elements:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)  # Using _parse_function from your question.
dataset = dataset.batch(20)  # Stack together 20 consecutive elements.
```

Comment: Lets say I have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] elements and I do: `batch(2)` would I get `[1,2], [2,3][3,4]..` or `[1,2][3,4][5,6]..` ? My goal would be the former. I guess it would result in the latter which I do not want.

Comment: Plus my output is not "batched" therefore the solution does not work at all.